# How to change title of the page of React-Router v6+ in history menu

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

There are a few questions like this on SO, but they are old and outdated and solutions don't work anymore

How can I change the title of the page so I don't have the same name in the History menu?

I can't find anything in the documentation I've tried:

```
<Link to="/home" title="Home"/>
```

but it doesn't work, I was looking at the code:

```js
export interface LinkProps
  extends Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, "href"> {
  reloadDocument?: boolean;
  replace?: boolean;
  state?: any;
  to: To;
}
```

no title only state object.

The state is visible in the migration guide from v5 but it doesn't say what it is used for. I guess it's a history state object but it has nothing to do with title AFAIK.

Is there any way to have a title change in history? This seems that pretty common behavior for routing libraries that modify history titles.

Comment: You could pass the title in route state and on the receiving routed component update the page title, or create a custom `Link` component that does this in an `onClick` handler, if *that* is what you are referring to.

Comment: @DrewReese I need to check if this will work since I only care about the title of the History Menu not the title of the document. And if they are handled by history API title of the page will have nothing to do with the history menu.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Passing the `title`

Given the React Router 6 code below:

```
// App.jsx
<Routes>
  <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
</Routes>
```

It can be modified as follows to pass custom titles to corresponding components:

```
// App.jsx
<Routes>
  <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage title="Home"/>} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage title="About" />} />
</Routes>

// HomePage.jsx
export function HomePage(props) {
  useEffect(() => document.title = props.title, [])
  
  return <div>...</div>
}
```

and then the `Link` can be used as per usual. 
It can be further "prettified" by applying the [HOC pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) - moving the title modification logic from each `element` component to the HOC.

---

## Parsing the URL

Alternatively, it is possible to pre-define a route-to-title mapping and reactively update the document's title whenever the url changes:

```
// App.jsx
const titles = {
  '/home': 'Home',
  '/about': 'About',
}

function App() {
  const location = useLocation()
  useEffect(
    () => (document.title = titles[location.pathname] ?? 'Hello World'),
    [location],
  )

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Although url params would require some additional parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to check if this will work since I don't care about the title of the document only the history menu when you right-click on the back button (in Chrome).

Comment: It works, I've expected that it will not work since you don't access `history.pushState` but it works as expected.

Comment: Happy to hear that! :)

Answer (score 1):

`react-helmet-async` library can also be used for changing the title.

```
//MyPage.jsx

import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';

function MyPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>My Page Title</title>
      </Helmet>
      {/* Rest of your component */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to define a title within [`handle`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.22.3/route/route#handle) on your Route objects. Then you can have a single root element which will obtain the `handle` using [`useMatches`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.22.3/hooks/use-matches) and set the document title. For example:

```js
const { StrictMode, Fragment, useEffect } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { Route, Routes, Outlet, Navigate, generatePath, useLoaderData, useMatches } = ReactRouter;
const { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Link } = ReactRouterDOM;

function Root() {
  const matches = useMatches()
  const { handle, data } = matches[matches.length - 1]
  const title = handle && handle.title(data)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (title) {
      document.title = title
    }
  }, [title])
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {title && <p>{`{ document.title = ${title} }`}</p>}
      <Outlet />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

function Sidebar() {
  const messages = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <div id="sidebar">
      <h1>Messages:</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          {messages.map((message) => (
            <li key={message.id}>
              <Link to={generatePath(`conversation/:id`, message)}>{message.title}</Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

function Messages() {
  return (
    <div id="messages">
      <Sidebar />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  )
}

const messages = [{
  id: 123,
  title: "Lorem Ipsum"
}];

function loadMessages() {
  return messages;
}

function Thread() {
  const thread = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <div id="thread">
      <h2>{thread.title}</h2>
      <p>{thread.body}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const threads = {
  123: {
    id: 123,
    title: "Lorem Ipsum",
    body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua..."
  }
}

function loadThread(args) {
  return threads[args.params.id];
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "messages",
        element: <Messages />,
        loader: loadMessages,
        handle: {
          title: () => "Messages",
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: "conversation/:id",
            element: <Thread />,
            loader: loadThread,
            handle: {
              title: (data) => `Thread - ${data.title}`,
            },
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        element: <Navigate to="/messages" replace={true}/>,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```css
#messages {
  height: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js" integrity="sha512-m7nhpWHotpucPI37I4lPovL28Bm2BhAMV8poF3F8Z9oOEZ3jlxGzkgvG0EMt1mVL1xydr1erlBbmN90js/ssUw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js" integrity="sha512-SKTL5rMewKkHVooCoONgJHCICK1otCPqPFduipyXVLWgtHHmsQgzXXHUP+SPyL4eU/knSpDkMXKlLedcHmWJpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@remix-run/router@1.15.3/dist/router.umd.min.js
"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/6.22.3/react-router.development.js" integrity="sha512-KUeAE/0tE5b0fuxjIWQeF0FCRvx6ZvgQsWLturKs5hPmtvLaESqlDhPf6BdghFofeqUvDLJKppOjLvVLJ8L+kA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/6.22.3/react-router-dom.development.js" integrity="sha512-V3xj7BgT+v9+QCAOo3yhwq0ybFqPVET7K/IZmKMnWjjeEXrbXLXR3dKC/KQRN42F4KLkIUed3/4aUus5p5L3nQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

With this approach there is no need to pass the title to each component, or wrap them all in a HOC, or parse the location.